# Learning Oracle, Setting boolean based on date

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I've just started a module in school on Oracle, I would like to ask for some help as I'm relatively new in regards to the capabilities of database systems in general.

For a part of one of my assignments, I'm trying to create a table where it stores customers details, there are columns of "LastBillPaidDate" as a DATE datatype and "hasUnpaidBill" and a BOOLEAN datatype.

When it comes to setting constraints, is there a way for me to make it such that when LastBillPaidDate is X days ago, I set hasUnpaidBill from false to true?

Thanks again and looking forward to learning from you all!

Comment: Sounds like its more of a trigger than constraints.

Comment: I don't know how you were able to set anything in Oracle SQL as data type BOOLEAN, since Oracle SQL does not support that data type (in violation of the SQL Standard which mandates support for it). Assuming it's a NUMBER data type with values 0 and 1, or it's a string data type with values 'True' and 'False' - but please confirm.

Comment: What you want to do is not at the very basic, intro level. The first thing that comes to mind is a calculated column (virtual column) - but that won't work, because calculated values must be deterministic, and SYSDATE is not. Rather, the correct solution is to store only the lastbillpaiddate in the table. Then create a **view** based on the table, with an additional "Boolean" column calculated using SYSDATE. Whenever you need to access this Boolean value, select from the view, not from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you have the `has_unpaid_bill` column in the table at the first place? It depends on `SYSDATE`. The requirement *smells like* a virtual column, but - you can't use `SYSDATE` there as it is not a deterministic function. Therefore, how about a **view** instead? Keep data you need in the table, but query the view:

Table and several sample records:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id                  number,
  3     last_bill_paid_date date
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, date '2020-11-09');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, date '2020-11-02');

1 row created.
```

View:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2    select id,
  3           last_bill_paid_date,
  4           case when trunc(sysdate) - last_bill_paid_date > 5 then 'Y'
  5                else 'N'
  6           end has_unpai_dbill
  7    from test;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from v_test;

        ID LAST_BILL_ H
---------- ---------- -
         1 09.11.2020 N
         1 02.11.2020 Y

SQL>
```

Comment: Hmm this looks doable, I will give it a try, thank you! :)